# Transpose vertically with a catch

Tags: linux, script, csv, awk, perl

I've been working through some issues preparing data for logstash ingestion.  I have a decent chunk of the process worked out but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.  Basically I need to transpose the following:

```
title,device1,device2
01/01/2001 00:30,data.dev1.ts1,data.dev2.ts1
01/02/2002 01:00,data.dev1.ts2,data.dev2.ts2
12/01/2003 15:00,data.dev1.ts3,data.dev2.ts3
```

to

```
01/01/2001 00:30,device1,data.dev1.ts1
01/01/2001 00:30,device2,data.dev2.ts1
01/02/2002 01:00,device1,data.dev1.ts2
01/02/2002 01:00,device2,data.dev2.ts2
12/01/2003 15:00,device1,data.dev1.ts3
12/01/2003 15:00,device2,data.dev2.ts3
```

What I'm currently doing is creating two documents.  One with the data for each timestamp (test.data.csv) and one with the device# for each timestamp(test.dev.csv Essentially this is like the test.data.csv except the device id replicated to replace the data).  Then I run the following perl code on both files to transpose vertically:

```
perl -F, -lane '$s=shift @F;print "$s,$_" for @F' test.data.csv > test.data2.csv
perl -F, -lane '$s=shift @F;print "$s,$_" for @F' test.dev.csv > test.dev2.csv
```

Then I strip the date from the datafile:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' test.data2.csv test3.csv
```

Merge the files:

```
awk -F, '{getline f1 <"test3.csv" ;print $1,$2,f1}' OFS=, test.dev2.csv > test4.csv
```

This is where my main problem arises.  This last awk command will run through the whole file fine except for the last line.  In the above example, the last line returned is:

```
,2/01/2003 15:00,device2
```

instead of what it should be:

```
12/01/2003 15:00,device2,data.dev2.ts3
```

any thoughts on why this is happening?  Is there something that I'm not getting with the getline option that behaves differently on the last line?

I'm also open to any suggestions for improving this workflow.  I don't like breaking the files apart or having to create two input files for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you're doing a lot of work. How about

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    NR == 1 {dev1 = $2; dev2 = $3; next}
    {
        print $1, dev1, $2
        print $1, dev2, $3
    }
' input
```

For an arbitrary number of devices, just use a loop:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    NR == 1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) device[i] = $i}
    NR  > 1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, device[i], $i}
' input
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion.  The only challenge is there are at least 500 devices.  (dev1....dev500). Plus they're random strings and may change in the next dataset.  This is good info though because I may be able to parse out and store the devs as variables.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, challenge accepted, answer updated.